# How to make the data in form to change based on previous and next button click using angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

i have used reactive forms, so based on selection of item in the right hand side, left side form is getting replaced with the particular row values.
Now instead of changing the row values by manual click, if i click on previous and next it must take up the previous value from list and vice versa, if the selected value is the first in table then previous must be disabled and next must be enabled, if selected value is last then next button to be disabled. I searched so many things but nothing helped me to solve my issues.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-gvhxne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
previousValue() {
    --this.userDetails.id
  }

  nextValue() {
    ++this.userDetails.id
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case correctly - it's your solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-3lwowg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

then based on userIndex value and the length of the list you can disable buttons.

Comment: Thanks for response, it is working partially, i want the right hand side also to be changed accordingly, i mean when it is on first item, when i click on next, the right hand side, active class must be on the second item and so on. If i am on first item, then previous must be disabled, if i am on last row then next must be disabled

Comment: Any idea about how can this be taken forward?

Comment: then instead of directive simply use a regular condition: [class.active]="userDetails && user.Id === userDetails.Id"
I've updated the stackblitz.